# Prove $\nabla u=Du$ if $u\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I'm studying an introduction to Sobolev spaces and I found this remark which I can't prove:

If $u\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)$, then $u$ admits weak gradient $Du$ and $Du=\nabla u$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

So I have two prove two things:

- If $u\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)$, then $u$ admits weak gradient: indeed if $u\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)\subset\mathcal{C}^0(\Omega)$, which is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ (but at this point I'd like to prove $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ -by this I denote the Sobolev space wrt the Dirichlet homogeneous problem-, and by definition it follows $u$ admits weak gradient, but I don't know how to conlcude);
- $Du=\nabla u$ a.e. in $\Omega$: I have no idea. I know I have to prove $$\int_{\Omega} w_i\phi dx=- \int_{\Omega}u\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} dx, $$ where $w_i$ is the $i^{th}$- component of $Du$, and $\phi\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, but apart from this I don't weven know what to write or which result I should use.

I know I should post my attempts, but I'm quite new to the subject and I havr many doubts. Any hint or advice would be much appreciate, thanks in advance-

Comment: You would be better off posting your attempts, irrespective of any 'doubts' you have. It is very difficult to help someone when you can't see what they have done.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a non-empty open set, then $C^1(\Omega)$ is in not contained in $L^2(\Omega)$. But you don't need that inclusion here.

Comment: Moreover, proving it in $1$ dimension is always a good start.

Comment: You're right, if $n=1$ and $\Omega=(a,b)$, then $$\int_a^b u\phi' dx=-\int_a^b u'\phi dx$$ as $u$ vanishes on the boundary, and $Du=u'$.